# Letting click/drag events through a UniformGrid

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, grid, wpf-controls

I have a UniformGrid with a bunch of buttons and lots of space between them. I want the clicks between the buttons to not get handled by the grid, but whatever is behind it, while keeping the functionality of the buttons as is.

I've tried setting

```
IsHitTestVisible="False"
```

on the grid, but this results in all buttons to not be intractable as well.

Comment: Are you setting the UniformGrid's Background?

Comment: @Clemens Thanks, your solution worked! It seems like the background was set in some internal styling for some reason, so I couldn't see it in the xaml. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you need to set the `Background` to be `null`, which is however the default value when you do not set the Background property at all.

```
Background="{x:Null}"
```